# Problem with Lorrain and Corson 2nd Ed?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, electrostatics, maxwell-equations, coulombs-law

I have both the second editions of Lorrain and Corson's *Electromagnetic Fields and Waves* and Jackson's *Classical Electrodynamics*.

I was reading Jackson's two chapters on Relativity and at one point he takes Lorrain and Corson to task (which is interesting in itself!) for wrongly deriving the existence of magnetic fields and Maxwell's equations from relativity.  He writes (section 12.3, page 578):

> At present it is popular in undergraduate texts and elsewhere (cites chapter 6 of Lorrain and Corson here) to attempt to derive magnetic fields and even the Maxwell equations from Coulomb's law of electrostatics and the kinematics of special relativity.  It should be immediately apparent that without additional assumptions this is impossible.

I have read through this section in Jackson but I am just to obtuse to catch exactly what the problem is.  So

1. What is the issue(s)? and,
2. Is the derivation of Lorrain and Corson exactly wrong, or if you make, or are aware of, certain assumption, the derivation is OK?
3. Finally, if anyone knows, do Lorrain and Corson clear this up in a later edition?

Appreciate any help!

---

I agree that some more information would probably help.  In chapter 6 of Lorrain and Corson, they illustrate the problem of calculating the force between two charges at rest in one reference frame, and moving with a constant velocity wrt to another reference frame.

In the first reference frame where the charges are stationary, the force on charge B is just that due to the coulomb force from charge A.  However, for the reference frame in which the charges are moving, if you Lorentz transform this coulomb force and do some algebra, you get an expression that appears to have a term precisely as you would expect from the magnetic field that now emanates from charge A, since it is moving, on charge B.  Hence, you have discovered the magnetic field.

Jackson address' this very problem and claims regarding those that think this discovers the magnetic field that:

> The reader may think that this seems quite reasonable, especially when he notes... the correct expression for the magnetic field...  But what if there had been a magnetic field in the [frame in which the particles are at rest]?

The answer to this question, he claims, is that the calculated expression for the magnetic field would be incorrect. This seems obvious - if another magnetic field is present, then the final form of the magnetic field would not be the simple expression that Lorrain and Corson calculate.

It appears that he is arguing that Lorrain and Corson have to state explicitly that they are assuming no other magnetic fields are present.  If true, this seem a little picky.

Jackson then also writes:

> The fact is that it is impossible from [the Lorentz transformed force] alone to deduce the existence of the magnetic field $\vec B$ and the magnetic force $q(\vec u X \vec B)/c$.  Other assumptions are necessary.  One key assumption or experimental fact is that in a frame K where all the *source charges* producing an electric field $\vec E$ are *at rest*, the force on a charge q is given by $\vec F = q \vec E$, *independent of the velocity $\vec u$* of the charge in that frame.

It is confusing as to what this assumption has to do with the problem.

Comment: Hmm, I can't quite find this statement in my 3rd edition of Jackson, and I don't have Lorrain and Corson, so it's kind of hard to answer your question. Perhaps you could quote more of the relevant books?

Comment: Certainly, it's impossible to derive E&M from just Coulomb's law plus special relativity. For example, gravity also formally obeys "Coulomb's law" but general relativity is clearly a different theory. You can distinguish the two by additionally postulating that charge is Lorentz invariant, which is enough to show that something like a magnetic force has to exist, but it's hard to go further without piling on lots more ad hoc assumptions.

Comment: It _is_ possible to derive Maxwell's equations from Coulombs law and special relativity. In this case, one regards the magnetic field to be a result of the electric field where $q$ (a Lorentz scalar) and $\bf j$ make up a 4-vector. This is done in Purcell's, _Electricity and magnetism_ .

Comment: @knzhou I have added more context.

Comment: The main target of the Lorentz transformation was to keep the Maxwell's equations convariant (before the advent of Special Relativity). So, to use them with Coulomb's Law to prove the existence of the magnetic field and force is circular.